# SAP UI5 application is unable to load custom UI5 library

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, ui5-tooling

I'm trying to develop a custom sap ui5 library withint the business application studio.

First things first: the documentation about this is horrible. I found many tutorials but none of them are telling me how to do things within the BAS and none of them is telling by how to deploy the library. So with try and error I was able to deploy the library (but I'm somehow not sure if it's the right way).

I've generated the ui5 library with yoman (https://blogs.sap.com/2021/01/24/kickstart-your-ui5-library-development-with-the-ui5-library-generator/):

> yo ui5-library

Then I figured out what needs to be in my ui5.yml and 5ui-deloy.yml so that the `npm run deploy` command works.

`ui5.yml`:

```yaml
specVersion: '2.2'
metadata:
  name: com.company.zcalibmntchk
type: library
framework:
  name: SAPUI5
  version: 1.84.24
  libraries:
    - name: sap.ui.core
    - name: themelib_sap_belize
    - name: themelib_sap_fiori_3
server:
  customMiddleware:
  - name: ui5-middleware-livereload
    afterMiddleware: compression
    configuration:
      extraExts: "xml,json,properties"
      path: ["src", "test"]
```

`ui5-deploy.yml`:

```yaml
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/schema/ui5.yaml.json

specVersion: '2.5'
metadata:
  name: com.company.zcalibmntchk
type: library
builder:
  resources:
    excludes:
      - /test/**
      - /localService/**
  customTasks:
    - name: deploy-to-abap
      afterTask: generateCachebusterInfo
      configuration:
        target:
          destination: {DESTINATION}
          url: {URL}
        credentials:
          username: env:DEPLOY_USR
          password: env:DEPLOY_PW
        app:
          name: Z_CA_LIB_MNTCHK
          package: ZCA_LIB
          transport: {TRANSPORT}
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "zcalibmntchk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ui5/cli": "^2.9.3",
    "@sap/ux-ui5-tooling": "^1.5.5",
    "karma": "^6.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-ui5": "^2.3.3",
    "ui5-middleware-livereload": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "ui5": {
    "dependencies": [
      "ui5-middleware-livereload"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ui5 build --clean-dest",
    "deploy": "npm run build && fiori deploy -y --config ui5-deploy.yaml && rimraf archive.zip",
    "undeploy": "fiori undeploy --config ui5-deploy.yaml"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED"
}
```

So with those settings the deployment finishes successfuly:

```
...
info builder:custom deploy-to-abap App available at http://{URL}/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/z_ca_lib_mntchk
info builder:custom deploy-to-abap Deployment Successful.
```

Now I'm trying to add the library like this inside an other fiori app by adding the name of the deployed library to the `dependencies` section inside the `mainfest.json` file:

`manifest.json`:

```json
...
"sap.ui5": {
        "flexEnabled": false,
        "dependencies": {
            ...
            "libs": {
                ...
                "zcalibmntchk": {}
            }
        },
        ...
```

(It also doesn't work with `com.company.zcalibmntchk`instead of `zcalibmntchk`)

But when I try to start the application I get the following error inside the js console:

```
Log-dbg.js:456 2022-06-23 15:17:20.681300 failed to load JavaScript resource: zcalibmntchk/library.js -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
Log-dbg.js:456 2022-06-23 15:17:20.682199 Failed to load component for container container - Error: failed to load 'zcalibmntchk/library.js' from resources/zcalibmntchk/library.js: script load error  
 Error: failed to load 'zcalibmntchk/library.js' from resources/zcalibmntchk/library.js: script load error
    at HTMLScriptElement.b (ui5loader-dbg.js:1330:5)
```

So somehow the application is not able to load the library ressource. So is there a problem within the implementation of the library inside the fiori app or is there a problem with the deployment?

Can't find any solutions on the internet and I'm pretty sure that somewhere out there people are using the functionality of custom sap ui5 libraries and I'm not the only one who's trying this.

---

Update:

I've changed according to the comment of @fmi21 the names inside the ui5.yml and ui5-deploy.yml from `com.company.zcalibmntchk` to just `zcalibmntchk` to make it similar in all files.

Then I've added the ressource root tag to the index.html according to the link @OpenUI Team posted.

Both doesn't bring the solution.

Somehow in the error message is stated that the app is trying to load the lib from `resources/zcalibmntchk/library.js`. And I think it should load it from somewhere else than the resources path because there's nothing there local. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are right, custom libraries are cool, and yes, the documentation kinda sucks. However about the problem: when I see UI5 scream at me 'failed to load X from Y' it usually means that the namespaces/loading paths are somehow messed up. In this example I believe it attempts to look for  'zcalibmntchk/library.js' when already inside 'zcalibmntchk' or something similar. Try to keep the package.json name the same as the ui5 module name and also import it like that too.

Comment: My first thought is that the path to your custom lib is not known to your app and that might be the reason it cannot be loaded. Have you already checked the answer(s) to this issue:  https://answers.sap.com/questions/13394169/custom-ui5-library-in-an-onpremise-environment-not.html

Comment: @fmi21 I've changed the names but it still doesnt work.

Comment: @OpenUI5Team I've added the resources tag to my html file as in your posted link stated but this also didnt't work. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found this questions, while I had the same problem, here's how I fixed it:
You need to add custom middleware (servestatic) in the UI5.yaml of the wrapper application (the app you run to see, what the lib looks like)

```
    - name: fiori-tools-servestatic
  beforeMiddleware: fiori-tools-proxy
  configuration:
    paths:
      - path: /resources/<lib here>
        src: <relative path to the lib in your folder>
        fallthrough: false
```